# Il : sujet impersonnel

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-impersonnels

La structure ci-après :

> Reste quelques cas particuliers

est-elle équivalente à celle ci-dessous ?

> Il reste quelques cas particuliers

Si c'est le cas, quand peut-on enlever cet il (sujet impersonnel) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elle est équivalente mais il vaut mieux corriger l'accord puisque le sujet est alors au pluriel :

> Rest**ent** quelques cas particuliers.

Comment: Merci. La chose drôle c'est que j'ai vu cet exemple dans un livre pour la grammaire (Grammaire du Français. Du mot au texte, p. 17) avec reste et non restent. Il m'a paru faux mais vu que le livre c'est une grammaire du supérieur j'ai fait confiance à elle. J'espère que c'était seulement une faute de frappe:-)! Quand peut-on se passer de cet il impersonnel ?

Comment: Le singulier est possible, mais plus rare. On considère qu'il y a ellipse du *il*. J'ai mis le pluriel car je considère que le sujet est *quelques cas particuliers*. On peut omettre ce *il* dans le style télégraphique ou dans le cours d'un texte plus long, comme introduction à la description de ces cas particuliers.

Comment: Alors, c'est ma faute plutôt car je n'ai pas précisé qu'il s'agit du titre d'une liste avec plusieurs cas particuliers (comme tu dis). Merci encore:-)!

Comment: Thanks, but can anyone explain in English please? I am relearning French after many years.  Is it something to do with an impersonal statement?

Comment: @Bluelion7 *Il reste xxx* is an impersonal statement so there is no agreement with the verb. Without the pronoun *il*, *reste* can be still considered to be used impersonally (with an implicit *il*) or, as I recommended in my answer, be used a regular way with a inverted subject, so with a plural agreement.