# Why is the verb not in plural form?

Tags: grammaire, accord

In the sentence" il me reste des croissants du weekend". Why isn't it " ils me restent...". Is it a set phrase? Thanks

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30514/il-sujet-impersonnel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you put it, this is a set phrase (une tournure impersonnelle). The personal pronoun "il" does not stand for anything: [français facile](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-28038.php).

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rester)) **II** être encore présent, disponible; subsister
>            **B.** − [En empl. impers., le suj. réel désigne un animé ou un inanimé concr. ou abstr.]
>
> 1. Il reste (+ subst.).
>    ♦ Quand les aunes eurent disparu, il restait les souches (Hémon, M. Chapdelaine, 1916, p. 63).
>    ♦ L'Europe était alors [au temps de Montesquieu] le meilleur des mondes possibles (...). La science était déjà assez belle, et les arts très délicats; il restait de la religion (Valéry, Variété II, 1929, p. 63).
>    ♦ Il reste les autres: les fidèles qui demeurent à mi-côte, qui luttent, succombent, se relèvent (Mauriac, Journal 2, 1937, p. 189).

Comment: It's misleading to call this a fixed phrase; the rule is entirely generalizable.

Comment: @LukeSawczak I can't figure out what you apply "entirely generalizable" to; you mean perhaps that you can conjugate these verbs ( "il existe", "il est", "il faut", …). Yes you can do that for those  verbs, but those impersonal turns are nevertheless fixed to an important degree, even if we can't see in them _perfectly fixed expressions_: the subject is only "il", no other pronoun will do, no noun is usable as subject, the meaning is not derived from the words (semantically fixed), for instance.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Here is a source that uses this very term as an identifying term for certain impersonal constructions of this sort: https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/zwh6tfr/revision/2.

Comment: When you said "fixed" I understood it as saying that "il reste" is a fixed expression, whereas this syntax is a general one for many verb types. If you meant that this syntax only works with "il" and no other pronouns, yes, that's true.

Answer (score 7):

Here, *rester* is used in an impersonal form.

That means the pronoun *il* (only third person singular allowed) is just a place holder and doesn't represent anything, like in *il pleut* (it's raining).

Comment: Merci beaucoup de m'aider avec ma première question. Je crois que je me souviens un peu l'utilisatin de cette phrase.

Answer (score 5):

As others have already answered, it's an impersonal form. You might like to note a few others which behave in a very similar way:

- *il existe plusieurs solutions* (several solutions exist)
- *il suffit de trois semaines pour finir le projet* (three weeks is enough to finish the project)
- *il arrive parfois des choses étranges* (strange things happen sometimes)
- *il en résulte deux conséquences* (there are two consequences of this)

Comment: A possible translation of "strange things are happening": "il se passe des choses étranges"